# Which is the best efficient way to get many-to-many relation count in laravel?

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I have `students` and `subjects` table in many-to-many relation (pivot table is student_subject).

Student Model

```
public function subjects()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany(Subject::class, 'student_subject');
}
```

Subject Model

```
public function students()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany(Student::class, 'student_subject');
}
```

Here I want the particular student subjects counts. I tried the below methods it's working fine but I want the best efficient way for this purpose.

1.

```
$student = Student::find($id);
$subject_count = $student->subjects()->count();
```

I checked the SQL query through laravel debuger it shows as below

```
select * from `students` where `students`.`id` = '10' limit 1

select count(*) as aggregate from `subjects` inner join `student_subject` on `subjects`.`id` = `student_subject`.`subject_id` where `student_subject`.`student_id` = 10 and `subjects`.`deleted_at` is null
```

2. 

```
$student = Student::withCount('subjects')->find($id);
$subject_count = $student->subjects_count;
```

I checked the SQL query through laravel debuger it shows as below

```
select `students`.*, (select count(*) from `subjects` inner join `student_subject` on `subjects`.`id` = `student_subject`.`subject_id` where `students`.`id` = `student_subject`.`student_id` and `subjects`.`deleted_at` is null) as `subjects_count` from `students` where `students`.`id` = '10' limit 1
```

3. 

```
$student = Student::find($id);
$subject_count = $student->loadCount('subjects')->subjects_count;
```

I checked the SQL query through laravel debuger it shows as below

```
select * from `students` where `students`.`id` = '10' limit 1

select `id`, (select count(*) from `subjects` inner join `student_subject` on `subjects`.`id` = `student_subject`.`subject_id` where `students`.`id` = `student_subject`.`student_id` and `subjects`.`deleted_at` is null) as `subjects_count` from `students` where `students`.`id` in (10)
```

4. 

```
$student = Student::find($id);
$subject_count = DB::table('student_subject')->where('student_id', $student->id)->count();
```

I checked the SQL query through laravel debuger it shows as below

```
select * from `students` where `students`.`id` = '10' limit 1

select count(*) as aggregate from `student_subject` where `student_id` = 10
```

According to the above ways which one is best and why? or if any different best way also there?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Doing `relation()->count()` is probably faster.

But if all you need is the count, `withCount()` should be better in terms of memory consumption.

Comment: Thanks for your time, I need actually best efficient way with the correct reason. Your answer didn't have any perfect reason.

Comment: No problem! See if this helps: https://stackoverflow.com/a/47779658/4886202

Comment: According to the above link, `withCount` is more memory efficient than `with`. What about `loadCount`?

Comment: So that would be eager loading vs lazy loading. Since you are not loading the count based on some dynamic condition, no need to run the 2nd query with `loadCount()`. So, therefore, `withCount()` is again a better option in your context.

Comment: I agree with your point. But Check my SQL query for each point. Accordingly, i am thinking then 4th one is best(take less time, because it didn't check any relationship with subjects)